# How to Style Images in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, node-canvas

I'm using node-canvas and I was wonder how style an imported image in canvas similar to how you would an image in CSS.

For example, how would I crop a square image in canvas to a circle. In CSS, all you need to do is set border radius to 50%.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasImageSource

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously you cannot use CSS in this case since CSS is applied to the DOM and not the the pixel based content of a Canvas element.

However the Canvas element has its own set of draw functions which allow to you replicate or at least approximate CSS rules.

Since you mentioned cropping an image to a circle I'll focus on this example. To achieve this effect you want to specify a [clipping region](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp) before drawing the image. Every pixel outside of the clipped region will not be drawn. Effectively this will crop the image to the clipped region.

In code:

```
// Retrieve canvas and get context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Save the context so we can undo the clipping region at a later time
context.save();

// Define the clipping region as an 360 degrees arc at point x and y
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

// Clip!
context.clip();

// Draw the image at imageX, imageY.
context.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY);

// Restore context to undo the clipping
context.restore();
```

I'd advice taking a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) page to give you an idea of what you can do with the Canvas element and the 2D rendering context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work in node, However you can do this with canvas;

1. The simplest way of doing it is using, as you intended, `border-radius`:

```css
canvas{border-radius:50%;}
```

2. An other way of doing it is by using the `ctx.clip()` method.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(125,120,100,0,2*Math.PI);

        // you clip the context
        ctx.clip();

        let img = document.querySelector("#testImg");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 20);
```

```html
<canvas width="250" height="240" >
  <img id="testImg" src="theImage.jpg">
</canvas>
```

3. Yet an other way of doing it is by using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop"`in this way:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 400,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 400,
  cy = ch / 2;

 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";

 let img = document.querySelector("#testImg");
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
 ctx.arc(cx, cx, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.fill();
```